# Continue after "throw new Exception"

Tags: c#, exception

When I throw an exception, my program breaks.

I want to continue my program after `throw new MatchException`.

My program checks the characters. When I put a wrong character, I get the exception and my program breaks.

My code:

```
public AbstractToken Peek()
{
    // Loop through all tokens and check if they match the input string
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, string> pair in _dictionary)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(_input.Substring(_counter), pair.Value);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            if (pair.Key.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractToken)))
            {
                // Create new instance of the specified type with the found value as parameter
                var token = (AbstractToken)Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Key, new object[] { match.Value, _counter }, null);
                return token;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new MatchException(_input[_counter].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), _counter);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are confused about what exceptions are and how exception handling works. Throwing an exception is saying something bad has happened. If no code in your program knows how to deal with that (ie catches the exception) then your program will break. If you don't want the program to break then either a) don't throw the exception or b) catch the exception and deal with whatever problem there is.

Answer (score 2):

Catch the exception [with a try catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `try` and `catch` to handle the exception. What you are doing now is throwing an `Exception`, which will result in a program crash.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions)

So what it should be:

```
public AbstractToken Peek()
    {
        // Loop through all tokens and check if they match the input string
        try
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, string> pair in _dictionary)
            {
            var test = _input.Length;
            // TODO: See if substring does not impose a to harsh performance drop
            Match match = Regex.Match(_input.Substring(_counter), pair.Value);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                if (pair.Key.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractToken)))
                {
                    // Create new instance of the specified type with the found value as parameter
                    AbstractToken token = (AbstractToken)Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Key, new object[] { match.Value, _counter }, null);

                    return token;

                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Do whatever u want
        }

    }
```

OR:

```
public AbstractToken Peek()
    {
        // Loop through all tokens and check if they match the input string
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, string> pair in _dictionary)
        {
            var test = _input.Length;
            // TODO: See if substring does not impose a to harsh performance drop
            Match match = Regex.Match(_input.Substring(_counter), pair.Value);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                if (pair.Key.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractToken)))
                {
                    // Create new instance of the specified type with the found value as parameter
                    AbstractToken token = (AbstractToken)Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Key, new object[] { match.Value, _counter }, null);

                    return token;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Both codes won't fire any `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

When you raise an Exception the software looks for a try-catch block in your stack to handle it. If this block isn't found, the program will crash.

The stack of calls save all functions that you called, in the bottom the first function and in the top the current function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try` and `catch` blocks and leave the `catch` block as empty.

```
try
{
       foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, string> pair in _dictionary)
        {
            var test = _input.Length;
            // TODO: See if substring does not impose a to harsh performance drop
            Match match = Regex.Match(_input.Substring(_counter), pair.Value);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                if (pair.Key.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractToken)))
                {
                    // Create new instance of the specified type with the found value as parameter
                    AbstractToken token = (AbstractToken)Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Key, new object[] { match.Value, _counter }, null);

                    return token;

                }
            }
        }
}
catch{ }
```

Comment: You seem to have removed the bit that actually throws the exception. Was this intentional? If so then why bother with the try catch?

Comment: @Chris Not Intentionally. I just guided that include try catch block...